# Sort controller in web api 2 help page

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

Is it possible to sort controllers in help page ? I don't want to sortby name but I want to choose which controller will be displayed in first in help pages.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

Please see the link below. You can modify the help pages as you please by going to Areas\HelpPage\Views\Help

To modify the initial help page, you can change the code in the Index.cshtml file accordingly.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/yaohuang1/2012/09/30/asp-net-web-api-help-page-part-1-basic-help-page-customizations/

Comment: Thanks for the link but It will be very usefull to not respond to a question with useless information. First this blog is for web api 1, not release 2, and there is no information on this blog that respond to my question. When I post a new question on this site, I am waiting for someone who has encountered the same problem to answer me, and I previously searched on google the answer. Thank you

Comment: I've never tried to order controllers/endpoints using a manual "ranking", but for sure you have to look on the file \Areas\HelpPage\Views\Help\Index.cshtml and adjust 
`var apiGroups = Model

.ToLookup(api => api.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor);`

Usually here I used to add the part for sorting controllers and endpoints by name. Maybe you need to add a Custom property to all ApiDescriptor and assign a int value and then sort by that number. Anyway swashbuckle is far better then this Ms Help Page, if I were in you I 'd change definitely to swagger.

Answer (score 0):

So, this is a million years old, but in case is of any use to anyone, this seems to work:

1. Create a custom attribute

   ```
   public class ControllerHelpIndexAttribute : Attribute
   {
       public ControllerHelpIndexAttribute(int index)
       {
           Index = index;
       }
       public int Index { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Put it on top of your controller

   ```
   [ControllerHelpIndex(2)]
   ```
3. Change help pages index.cshtml

   ```
   // Group APIs by controller
   ILookup<HttpControllerDescriptor, ApiDescription> apiGroups = Model
   .OrderBy(m =>   m.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<ControllerHelpIndexAttribute>().FirstOrDefault()!=null?m.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<ControllerHelpIndexAttribute>().FirstOrDefault().Index:-1)
   .ToLookup(api => api.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor);
   ```

Hope it is of any use.